# how to Unstretch Material on Object on 2.8?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to make a city with lights on windows. Here is what I have done so far:[image]

I have my city and my material for the window lights, but as you can see the tower in the back has the texture strech all the way up, I would like to know if there is a way to "unstrech" it.
I have tried to check on the UV map but I found nothing.

Does Anyone have an idea how ot make this ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you like to control the texture using the UV's you should change the 'Texture Coordinate' node to UV instead of GENERATED.

Comment: thx for your answer, I have found something, by changing the "Scale" vector on the mapping editor, I can get what I want, but I would like to change this value according to the scale of my object, any idea to do this throught the nodes ?